# Let $V = \Bbb V(zx,zy) \subset \Bbb A^n$. Show that the ideal $I(V)$ is not prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

> Let $V = \Bbb V(zx,zy) \subset \Bbb A^n$. Show that the ideal $I(V)$ is not prime.

$V$ is the union of the $z$-axis and the $xy$-plane and we can express it as $V=\Bbb V(z) \cup \Bbb V(x,y)$. Now if $I(V)$ were prime we would have that for $fg \in I(V)$ either $f \in I(V)$ or $g \in I(V)$.

Suppose that $fg \in I(V)= \{f \in \Bbb C[x,y,z] \mid f (x)=0, \forall x \in V\}$, then $$f(x)g(x)=0, \forall x \in V,$$

however $V=\Bbb V(z) \cup \Bbb V(x,y)$ so $$f(x)g(x)= 0, \forall x \in \Bbb V(z) \text{ or } \forall x \in \Bbb V(x,y).$$

how can I use this to my advantage here? I'm trying to construct as elementary proof as possible here.

If $f(x)g(x)=0, \forall x \in \Bbb V(z)$, then can I argue that $\exists x' \in \Bbb V(x,y)$ such that $f(x')g(x') \ne 0$ which would imply that $f$ nor $g$ is in $I(V)$? I don't think I can do this, but I don't know why I couldn't.

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, it suffices to simply provide an example of $f, g$, such that $fg \in I(V)$, but neither of them is in the ideal. Namely, you can take $f = z$, $g =xy$

Comment: You're right! I just couldn't come up with any examples so I tried to approach it the way I provided. It's somewhat hard for me still to figure out counterexamples as I'm lacking the intuition for the ideal $I(V)$.

Comment: Well, it might be useful to know that there is a general theorem saying that the ideal of a variety is prime iff the variety is irreducible. Thus you basically have constructed a counterexample yourself, when noticed that $V = V(z) \cup V(x, y)$. With respect to ideals it means precisely that $I(V) = (z) \cdot (x, y)$.

Comment: Are you concluding this "With respect to ideals it means precisely that $I(V) = (z) \cdot (x, y)$" from the nullstellensatz? I.e $I(\Bbb V(zx,zy)) = \sqrt{(zx,zy)}$?

Comment: I guess it is true over any field, so you don’t need Nullstellensatz to see that - to be 100% accurate, you can check that by hand, but the idea is that arbitrary sums of ideals correspond to intersections of algebraic sets and finite product — to finite unions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polynomials $f(x,y,z)=xy$ and $g(x,y,z)=z$ are not in $I(V)$. Indeed, $f$ doesn't vanish at the point $(1,1,0)\in V$ while $g$ doesn't vanish at the point $(0,0,1)\in V$. However, we clearly have $fg\in I(V)$. So the ideal is not prime.

Comment: May I ask how did you conclude that $f$ and $g$ aren't in $I(V)$?

Comment: @Jonas Again, elements of $I(V)$ are polynomials that vanish on all points of $V$. We have $(1,1,0)\in V$, but $f(1,1,0)\ne 0$, and so $f\notin I(V)$. Similarly for $g$.